# Find by XPath with multiple elements, seperate lines

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find an element based on if it contains text in two separate places, sorry for lack of terms, I'm not very experienced in HTML. Here is the HTML on the website:

```
<article>
    <div class="inner-article">
        <a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/tx74hqf5v/lmfhiu5p8">
            <img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/161584/vi/-tUn9HN7n-0.jpg" alt=" tun9hn7n 0">
        </a>
        <h1>
            <a class="name-link" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/tx74hqf5v/lmfhiu5p8">Fade Stripe L/S Top</a>
        </h1>
        <p>
            <a class="name-link" href="/shop/tops-sweaters/tx74hqf5v/lmfhiu5p8">Brown</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

Searching for the element seperatly works, but when I try and use "and", it doesn't work. Here is what works:

```
driver[task].FindElement(By.XPath($"//a[contains(text(),'Fade')]")).Click();
driver[task].FindElement(By.XPath($"//a[contains(text(),'Brown')]")).Click();
```

What I have tried:

```
driver[task].FindElement(By.XPath($"//a[contains(text(),'Fade') and //a[contains(text(),'Brown')]")).Click();
```

No luck, please help, thank you! I'm using c# and Selenium :)

Comment: I pulled the linked HTML into the question. You always want to put all the relevant info in the question itself. These questions can last for years and links can go dead. If it was a LOT of HTML, it would be more reasonable to put a subset of it in the question and then add a link to the large amount of HTML for those that wanted to see it.

Comment: Your first locator contains the word 'Zip' but the HTML you posted doesn't. I'm assuming that was a mistake? Please update your locators to match what you attempted with the posted HTML.

Comment: updated, sorry. And I couldn't figure out how to display the HTML correctly in the question, that is why I went about it through pastebin. My apologies.

Comment: No problem. You can format HTML just like you would code. Four space of indent on the left. If you need other formatting help, click the ? icon when you are editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in cases like this is find an "anchor" element and then find the two (or more) elements that are children of that anchor.

To match the HTML you posted, I'm going to look for "Fade Stripe L/S Top" and "Brown". I'm going to use the `ARTICLE` tag as my anchor.

I usually start by doing something simple and then building on it. Let's find the "Fade Stripe L/S Top" text in an `A` tag under the `ARTICLE` anchor.

```
//article//a[.='Fade Stripe L/S Top']
^ double slash means at any level
  ^ the ARTICLE tag
         ^ at any level below that
           ^ an A tag
            ^ that contains the exact text "Fade Stripe L/S Top"
```

Now let's do the same thing but for the "Brown" text

```
//article//a[.='Brown']
```

Really simple... from your post, I'm assuming you could have done this yourself or are at least following along. Now let's flip it slightly and use the `ARTICLE` as the anchor... find an `ARTICLE` tag that has a descendant `A` tag that contains "Brown".

```
//article[.//a[.='Brown']]
```

This returns the `ARTICLE` tag instead of the `A` tag because this

```
[.//a[.='Brown']]
 ^ start looking at the tag previously specified
  ^ at any level
    ^ the rest you already know
```

indicates that it is a property of the `ARTICLE` tag (it's enclosed in []s). So now we have the `ARTICLE` that contains a link with the text "Brown". Now we just need to make sure it also contains a link with the text "Fade Stripe L/S Top" and return that `A` tag.

```
//article[.//a[.='Brown']]//a[.='Fade Stripe L/S Top']
^ this first part is from above
                          ^ this is where the new stuff starts but it should be recognizable
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Basically we find the `ARTICLE` tag that contains one of the links (using the `[.//tag[property]]` syntax) and then find the descendant `//tag[property]` and so on.

Just to further expand this... we can look for any number of properties. Hopefully this will help you see the pattern better.

```
//article [.//a[.='Brown']] [.//a[.='Text2']] [.//a[.='Text3']] //a[.='Fade Stripe L/S Top']
```

I added spaces between the properties for emphasis.

```
//article [.//a  [.='Brown']] //a  [.='Fade Stripe L/S Top']
//tag     [.//tag[property ]] //tag[property]
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you for the help, really apperciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do it Or not and

```
a=> driver[task].FindElement(By.XPath($"//a[contains(text(),'Zip')]")).Click();
b=> driver[task].FindElement(By.XPath($"//a[contains(text(),'Brown')]")).Click();
```

is not 'a' AND 'b' it is 'a' OR 'b'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I was using C#, will this work for c# @Inam Gull